# lex file not executing

Tags: compiler-construction, yacc, lex, lexical-analysis

I was tring to doing my assignment. That is "Write a program using YACC specifications to implement syntax analysis phase of compiler to validate type and syntax of variable declaration in C program."
Here I have Assi6.l file with code.

Assi6.l file

```
%{
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<y.tab.h>
    int a;
%}
datatype int|float|char|string|boolean
digits [0-9]
letters [A-Za-z]
identifiers {letters}({letters}|{digits})*
comma ,
SC ;
%%
{datatype}{return datatype;}
{identifiers}{return identifiers;}
{comma} {return comma;}
{SC} {return SC;}
\n {return 0;}
%%
```

Output: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xG4iE.jpg)

Can anyone tell me what is wrong at line 13. I am not getting anything

Comment: Please use a code block instead of posting an image.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I will make sure to use a code block in the future instead of posting images.

Answer (score 1):

You need a space (or tab) between the pattern and the action in the rule.  As it is, lex thinks the pattern on line 13 is `{datatype}{return`.

Add a space after the pattern:

```
{datatype} {return datatype;}
```

which makes the pattern be just `{datatype}`

Comment: Thank you for your help. now It is executing successfully.